# My program can't get result from addChildEventListener in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

DB structure

```
questions
  questionId
    options
     optionId
       label         
       score
       ...
```

First I created a database reference in my code .

```
  mQuestionDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions").child(questionId).child("options").child(optionId);
```

Then inside an option I changed the value of score using transaction.

```
mQuestionDatabaseReference.child("score").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() { ...
```

I can successfully update score value. Now I want to know if the score is already updated in the database so I can update my UI using **addChildEventListener**.

```
 mQuestionDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {..
```

This one is okay. Now, I just wanna know if the score child of the option is updated not the whole option. So I did thid

```
mQuestionDatabaseReference.child("score").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {..
```

Now this new child event listener can't get the result when I successfully update an option.

Comment: what kind of data you have inside `/optionId/score`?

Comment: an int type data (number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding a `ChildEventListener` in `/optionId/score` but **score doesn't actually have any child, so the callback will never be triggered**.

In this case you should be using `ValueEventListener`.

```
mQuestionDatabaseReference.child("score").addValueEventListener(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //dataSnapshot.getValue ...
        }
});
```

Get more info in [firebase events documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#listen_for_events).

Comment: Well  guess I need to read method names more, hahaha. Thank you!

Comment: @devadnqpnd hsuahsua. this happens all the time. :) Congratz for the well asked question!